# Android Facebook 3.0 Customize login dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am using the new FacebookSDK and want to use the SSO login feature. What happens is that you get a very ugly [Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/native-login/) with the requested permissions listed in them. I would rather have the old way(see hackbook sample, still uses sdk 2.0 Facebook.authorize()) where you get redirected to an Activity of the Facebook app that has a nice layout.

I searched through the whole facebookSDK and stackOverflow but couldn't find a way to change the dialog. I could still use the hackbook way with the Facebook.authorize() function. but if i use it Eclipse crosses it through because it's Deprecated.

If you know a way that would help me please let me know

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I believe [WebDialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/WebDialog/) is what you are looking for.